# Relative fiscal quarter calculation formula

Tags: excel, date, fiscal

Requesting guidance calculating a field in Excel, called **Relative Fiscal Quarter**. This would be a numeric field containing positive/negative integers (no decimals). This field will be based on dates field which has dates from Jan 1, 2009 to Dec 31, 2037.

| Dataset Fields | Excel Column | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dates | A | None |
| Fiscal Year | B | =IF(MONTH([@dates])>=11, YEAR([@dates])+1, YEAR([@dates])) |
| Fiscal Quarter | C | =IF(MONTH([@dates])>=11,CEILING((MONTH([@dates])-10)/3,1), CEILING((MONTH([@dates])+2)/3,1)) |
| Today's Date | D | =TODAY() |
| Today's Date Fiscal Year | E | =IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=11,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY())) |
| Today's Date Fiscal Quarter | F | =IF(MONTH(TODAY()) >= 11, CEILING((MONTH(TODAY()) - 10) / 3, 1), CEILING((MONTH(TODAY()) + 2) / 3, 1)) |
| Current Fiscal Quarter | G | =IF([@[Fiscal Year]]=[@[Todays Date Fiscal Year]],IF([@[Fiscal Quarter]]=[@[Todays Date Fiscal Quarter]],TRUE,FALSE)) |
| Relative Fiscal Quarter (Desired Output) | F | ? |

Sample data:

[image]

For this use case, the fiscal quarter begins in November.

| Fiscal Qtr. | Months |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-FQ1 | Nov, Dec, Jan |
| 2023-FQ2 | Feb, Mar, Apr |
| 2023-FQ3 | May, Jun, Jul |
| 2023-FQ4 | Aug, Sep, Oct |

Relative Fiscal Quarter should be 0 for all dates that are the current fiscal quarter, -1 for the prior fiscal quarter and so on. Additionally, the field should be 1,2,3... for future fiscal quarters. Value of Relative Fiscal Quarter and Current Fiscal Quarter will change as fiscal quarters pass.

Attempted to calculate the Relative Fiscal Quarter using this formula, but as you can see it only partially succeeds.

```
=IF(\[@\[Current Fiscal Quarter\]\], 0, (\[@\[Fiscal Year\]\] - \[@\[Todays Date Fiscal Year\]\]) \* 4 + IF(MONTH(\[@dates\]) \>= 11, CEILING((MONTH(\[@dates\]) - 10) / 3, 1), CEILING((MONTH(\[@dates\]) + 2) / 3, 1))) - (\[@\[Fiscal Year\]\] -\[@\[Todays Date Fiscal Year\]\]) \* 4
```

Sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping with your sample table structure, the following function should work in the *Relative Fiscal Quarter* column:

```
=([@[Fiscal Year]]-[@[Todays Date Fiscal Year]])*4+([@[Fiscal Quarter]]-[@[Todays Date Fiscal Quarter]])
```

Answer (score 2):

This maybe do what you want

```
=INT((MONTH(NOW())-((YEAR(NOW())-YEAR([@dates]))*12+MONTH(NOW())-MONTH([@dates]))-11)/3)+1
```

Comment: Thanks but since this uses the NOW() function, it is capturing the calendar month and year, the ask was for relative fiscal year. I think @DjC solution addresses this. Thanks again 

Comment: @p2c4 This is obvious because from where would you know the 0 point. But this is your choice.